# Enhanced image plugin not working correctly when custom styles have been applied

Tags: css, image, plugins, ckeditor

For my website we use custom style sheets that are stored locally on our server and are injected into the webpages. However when i add them to CKEditor and then attempt to resize or move an image with the enhanced image plugin they cannot be resized or moved at all. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there anyway around it?

edit: So i add my css files using

```
config.contentsCss = ['http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans',
 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif',
  'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono',
   'http://192.168.0.50/css/new/all.css?v=1" media="all',
    'http://192.168.0.50/css/new/templates.css?v=1',
     'http://192.168.0.50/css/pre_review/colors.css?v=1',
      'http://192.168.0.50/css/pre_review/paged_test.css?v=2',
       'http://192.168.0.50/css/pre_review/bootstrap.min.css?v=1',
        'http://192.168.0.50/css/pre_review/main.css?v=1',
        'text/css'];
```

I have also installed the Enhanced Image plugin to allow me to resize and move images around. however when i insert an image on to the page the source looks like

```
<p><img alt="" height="239" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png" width="239" /></p>
```

when i originally set the image width and height in the popup panel i set the values to 2 and 2, these values do nothing to edit the actual size of the image. It still displays at the full size of 239x 239.

I know that it is my added styles that are causing this error as it works fine without them, However i do need them. is there anyway around this without having to remove the styles?

Comment: Please clarify your question and attach some examples.

Comment: Sure i'l add an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `contentsCss` has some weird parts like the last item or this `'http://192.168.0.50/css/new/all.css?v=1" media="all'`. Please verify that all this works. Incorrect rules may affect CKEditor.

Second, the issue may be very simple - your CSS most likely affect widgets styling. Disable loading your CSS files one by one and see which one breaks the Enhanced Image plugin. Then find the rule that breaks it and then improve the rule so it does not affect images.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it was the bootstrap.min.css file that is conflicting. will need to discuss alternatives.